# Is this C++ AtomicInt implementation correct?

Tags: c++, arm, embedded, atomic, volatile

Premise: I'm working with an ARM embedded (almost bare-metal) environment where I don't even have C++11 (with `std::atomic<int>`) available, so please avoid answers like "*just use standard C++ `std::atomic<int>`*": **I can't**.

Is this ARM [implementation](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/2Xr-kP) of AtomicInt correct? (assume ARM architecture is **ARMv7-A**)

Do you see some synchronization issue? Is it `volatile` required/useful?

```cpp
// File: atomic_int.h

#ifndef ATOMIC_INT_H_
#define ATOMIC_INT_H_

#include <stdint.h>

class AtomicInt
{
public:
    AtomicInt(int32_t init = 0) : atom(init) { }
    ~AtomicInt() {}

    int32_t add(int32_t value); // Implement 'add' method in platform-specific file

    int32_t sub(int32_t value) { return add(-value); }
    int32_t inc(void)          { return add(1);      }
    int32_t dec(void)          { return add(-1);     }

private:
    volatile int32_t atom;
};

#endif
```

```cpp
// File: arm/atomic_int.cpp

#include "atomic_int.h"

int32_t AtomicInt::add(int32_t value)
{
    int32_t res, prev, tmp;

    asm volatile(

    "try:    ldrex   %1, [%3]\n"     // prev = atom;
    "        add     %0, %1, %4\n"   // res = prev + value;
    "        strex   %2, %0, [%3]\n" // tmp = outcome(atom = res); // may fail
    "        teq     %2, #0\n"       // if (tmp)
    "        bne     try"            //     goto try; /* add failed: someone else modified atom -> retry */

    : "=&r" (res), "=&r" (prev), "=&r" (tmp), "+mo" (atom)  // output (atom is both in-out)
    : "r" (value)                                           // input
    : "cc");                                                // clobbers (condition code register [CPSR] changed)

    return prev; // safe return (local variable cannot be changed by other execution contexts)
}
```

Also, I'm trying to achieve some code reuse, that is why I isolated just one basic function to implement in platform-specific code (`add()` method inside `arm/atomic_int.cpp`).

Is `atomic_int.h` really *portable* as it is across different platforms/architectures/compilers? Is this approach *feasible*? (With *feasible* I mean *feasible for every platform to guarantee atomicity by implementing just the `add()` method*).

[here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/_56-lg) is the corresponding ARM GCC 8.3.1 implementation of the same function. Apparently, the only real difference is the presence of `dmb` before and after. Are they really needed in my case? Why? Do you have an example where my `AtomicInt` (without `dmb`) fails?

UPDATE: fixed implementation, removed `get()` method to solve atomicity and alignment issues. Now the `add()` behaves like a standard `fetchAndAdd()`.

Comment: `volatile` keyword in C++ means don't optimize via variable. So `get()` method benefits from it. Though, in general, volatile is about to deprycates in C++. If your system cannot built-in syncronize 32-bit data, then you have little choice but to use mutexes - spinlock in the very least.

Comment: What version of the arm architecture are you using? armv-7?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__ATOMIC_INT_H_`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: The member name `atomic` is probably best not used to avoid confusion with `std::atomic`, although it begs the question why you wouldn't just use that in any case.

Comment: Added ARM architecture, renamed `__ATOMIC_INT_H_` identifier.

Comment: Renamed `atomic` with `atom`.
@clifford if you're asking me why I'm not using std::atomic, it is because the cross-compiler I'm using does not support C++11.

Comment: @gentooise : Fair enough.  Is platform portability really an issue given the in-line assembler - you'd have to rewrite that in any case for each platform.  Your compiler probably has `__attribute__` or `#pragma` directives to force a specific alignment, or the compiler documentation will tell you what it guarantees or not otherwise.  But yes, the implementation will be platform, architecture and/or compiler specific.

Comment: @Clifford I'm working on a sort of framework and I wanted to achieve complete portability for all the rest of the software that will use framework classes (like `AtomicInt`). At the same time, I want the framework itself to be "easily" ported, i.e. minimizing and isolating the framework code that is platform/architecture/compiler specific, so that I will have to rewrite only specific portions of the framework when porting.

So my question here is dual: **did I isolate the necessary/sufficient portion** of `AtomicInt`? **Did I implemented that portion correctly for ARMv7-A**?

Comment: The code in @Maxim Egorushkin's answer has a memory barrier before returning.  Seems you don't need one before the `ldrex`, but the ARM documentation I found isn't too clear.

Comment: @marko I have your same doubts, documentation it's not very clear to me. I'm not sure about `dmb`, and I'm also not sure if `clrex` is needed to reset exclusive monitors during context switches (or is it done automatically) on Cortex-A.

Comment: The get function also needs to be in inline asm or you can't guarantee atomic read. It's not enough that the variable is 32 bits - a C compiler is likely to use multiple instructions to for example temporarily store the value in a register.

Comment: @Lundin: you are right, in fact I removed the `get()` method. Please focus on implementation v2 without `get()` method.

Comment: Seems to me that you need to add a memory barrier as `volatile` doesn't guarantee that. And (as far as I know)   `asm volatile("...")` is a compiler specific extension so it can be compiler specific.

Comment: @TarickWelling: for `asm volatile("...")` it is ok for me to be compiler specific, I only want `atomic_int.h` to be portable (question edited: I further clarified my portability issue).
For memory barrier, I would like to understand _why_ and in which cases it is needed.

Comment: If the inline `asm` has all the needed specification, and everything is access with inline `asm`, then inherently no variable needs to be volatile: volatile applies to access in C/C++, not in code linked (external assembly code) or fused (inline assembly) into C/C++.

Comment: @curiousguy good point, but I'm not sure if all implementations will use inline assembly so I would rather keep the `volatile` (if it's not harmful) in order to be more generic.

Comment: I did further research on memory barriers: they are only needed in case of multi-core architectures (or in general when the accessed memory is **shared** with other devices) and only if the CPU performs **out-of-order execution**. In my case, since I'm assuming **ARMv7-A** (that has different [implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_ARMv7-A_cores) matching this description), I should add memory barriers in order to be compatible with all ARMv7-A cores (even if the core I'm currently working on is single-issue/in-order and would not need them).

Answer (score 2):

If you use `gcc` may be you can use [Legacy `__sync` Built-in Functions for Atomic Memory Access](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fsync-Builtins.html#g_t_005f_005fsync-Builtins):

```
void add(int volatile& a, int value) {
    __sync_fetch_and_add(&a, value);
}
```

[Generates](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Bt3mNz):

```
add(int volatile&, int):
.L2:
        ldxr    w2, [x0]
        add     w2, w2, w1
        stlxr   w3, w2, [x0]
        cbnz    w3, .L2
        dmb     ish
        ret
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not using `gcc`, and in any case I don't want to bind the implementation to any specific compiler. Thank you anyway for your hint, at least it tells me that my ARM `add()` part should be correct. What's the difference between `ldxr` and `ldrex`?

Comment: This is ARM8 (e.g.64bit) rather than one of the 32-bit versions.

Comment: I managed to get the corresponding code by specifying the target architecture: [link](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/NXCI41). It seems GCC actually puts `dmb` before and after the `ldrex`/`strex` loop.

Comment: I think this is the good approach but to make it compiler independent just go to https://godbolt.org/z/WB8rxw type in the function you want using gcc builtins and copy the corresponding assembly output. Be sure to match the -march parameter with the specific version of ARM.